# procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied C# con sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms, sql-server-2014

el procedure no recibe ningún parametro, y tampoco mando ningún parametro desde c#
Me da error cuando agrego un nuevo hotel y voy a otra ventana para ver los hoteles.
Pero cuando no agrego ningún hotel y voy directo a ver los hoteles no marca error y me los carga perfectamente en el datagrid

```
public DataTable PutHoteles()
        {
            var msg = "";
            DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                _conexion.Open();
                conectar();
                _comandosql.CommandText = "HotelesPaisCiudad";
                _comandosql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                _comandosql.CommandTimeout = 1200;
                _adaptador.SelectCommand = _comandosql;

                _comandosql.ExecuteNonQuery();
                _comandosql.Parameters.Clear();
                _adaptador.Fill(tabla);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                msg = "Excepción de base de datos: \n";
                msg += e.Message;
                MessageBox.Show(msg, "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                desconectar();
            }
            return tabla;
        }

//Procedure en sql server
if exists(Select 1 From sysobjects where name= 'HotelesPaisCiudad' and type ='P')
begin
DROP PROCEDURE HotelesPaisCiudad
end
go
CREATE PROCEDURE HotelesPaisCiudad
AS
begin
Select IdHotel, NombreH AS 'Nombre hotel', ColoniaH AS 'Colonia', CPH AS 'Código Postal', CalleH AS 'Calle', NumH AS 'Numero', #Piscinas AS 'Numero Piscinas', #habitaciones AS 'Numero habitaciones', zonaturistica AS 'Zona turistica', #ServiciosDisponibles AS 'Numero Servicios Disponibles', FPlaya AS 'Frente playa', SalonEventos, FechaIniOperaciones'Inicio operaciones',IdUsuarioAtiende, Usuario AS 'Usuario atiende', NombrePais AS 'Nombre Pais', IdPaisHotel, nombreCiudad AS 'Nombre Ciudad', IdCiudadHotel
From Hotel H JOIN Pais P 
ON H.IdPaisHotel=P.IdPais 
INNER JOIN Ciudad C
ON H.IdCiudadHotel=C.IdCiudad
INNER JOIN Usuario U
ON H.IdUsuarioAtiende=U.NoNomina
end
go
```

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Te sobra el execute nonQuery, y el Parameters clear. Adicionalmente, es recomendable utilizar estructuras using para las conexiones, puesto que estos bloques se encargan de cerrar y realizar la llamada a dispose.

```
try
        {
            using (SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand _comandosql = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    _comandosql.Connection = _connection;
                    _comandosql.CommandText = "HotelesPaisCiudad";
                    _comandosql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    _comandosql.CommandTimeout = 1200;
                    _comandosql.Connection.Open();
                    using (SqlDataAdapter _adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(_comandosql))
                    {

                        _adaptador.Fill(tabla);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            msg = "Excepción de base de datos: \n";
            msg += e.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(msg, "Warning!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            throw e;
        }
```